# How to find value of $x$ in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I'm trying to solve for x in terms of a.

Is there any way to simplify the following?

$$a = x + \sqrt{ x^2+x} $$

I've been staring at this for a while and nothing immediate comes to mind...

Comment: $a - x= \sqrt{ x^2+x}$ Square both sides. Take care that squaring could introduce extra solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use
$$
a = x + \sqrt{x^2 + x} \iff \\
(a-x)^2 = x^2 + x \wedge a \ge x \iff \\
a^2 - 2ax = x \wedge a\ge x \iff \\
a^2 = (2a + 1) x \wedge a\ge x \\
x = \frac{a^2}{2a+1} \wedge a \ge x \wedge a\ne -1/2
$$
Let us have a look:

[image]

The red graph is $a(x)$ and the blue graph the unrestricted $x(a)$. So $a\ge x$ reduces it to the correct inverse.

Comment: You should explain the notation.

Comment: The $\wedge$ is a logical and.

Comment: Doesn't the "$+\sqrt{x^2+x}$" mean that $a\ge x$?

Comment: Yes, that has to be carried into the next line.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a-x)^2=x^2+x=a^2-2ax+x^2\\
a^2-2ax=x\\
x={a^2\over 2a+1}$$